# PHP nesting elseif statement within an if statement

Tags: php, nested

First of all, I am new to coding and php and I am trying to create a profile page where the user can edit their user profile.

The form is created, but I am having trouble with making sure the correct fields are filled. From what I have learned and in my head, nesting "elseif" statements within an "if" statement would be the most logical way to accomplish what Im looking for, but apparently something isn't working correctly because the page is broken when I refresh. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-submit'])){
    if($firstName == NULL) {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button> Please enter your first name to continue!</div>";
    }
    elseif ($lastName == NULL){
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button> Please enter your last name to continue!</div>";
    }
    elseif ($txtuname == NULL){
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button> Please enter your username to continue!</div>";
    }
    elseif ($txtemail == NULL){
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button> Please enter your email to continue!</div>";
    }
    elseif ($busName == NULL) {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button> Please enter your business name to continue!</div>";
    }
    elseif ($busEmail == NULL) {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button> Please enter your business email to continue!</div>";
    }

    $firstName = trim($_POST['fname']);
    $lastName = trim($_POST['lname']);
    $txtuname = trim($_POST['uname']);
    $txtemail = trim($_POST['email']);
    $busName = trim($_POST['busname']);
    $busEmail = trim($_POST['busemail']);
    $busAddress = trim($_POST['busaddress']);
    $busSuite = trim($_POST['bussuite']);
    $busCity = trim($_POST['buscity']);
    $busState = trim($_POST['busstate']);
    $busZip = trim($_POST['buszip']);

    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button> You are finally on the right path!</div>";
}
else {
    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button> Something is really screwed up!</div>";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the page is broken when I refresh"? Right now, if `isset($_POST['btn-submit'])` is `true`, $msg will always have the last value. You're overwriting it, so the value you assign on the if/elseif chain won't stick. Besides, you're doing those checks before assigning the variables.

Comment: I am getting a "This page isn’t working" error in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are assigning the variables before you test them in the elseif.

Try with this:

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-submit'])){
    $firstName = trim($_POST['fname']);
    $lastName = trim($_POST['lname']);
    $txtuname = trim($_POST['uname']);
    $txtemail = trim($_POST['email']);
    $busName = trim($_POST['busname']);
    $busEmail = trim($_POST['busemail']);
    $busAddress = trim($_POST['busaddress']);
    $busSuite = trim($_POST['bussuite']);
    $busCity = trim($_POST['buscity']);
    $busState = trim($_POST['busstate']);
    $busZip = trim($_POST['buszip']);

    if($firstName == NULL) {
      $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button> Please enter your first name to continue!</div>";
    }
    elseif ($lastName == NULL){
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button> Please enter your last name to continue!</div>";
    }
    elseif ($txtuname == NULL){
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button> Please enter your username to continue!</div>";
   }
   elseif ($txtemail == NULL){
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button> Please enter your email to continue!</div>";
    }
    elseif ($busName == NULL) {
         $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button> Please enter your business name to continue!</div>";
    }
    elseif ($busEmail == NULL) {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button> Please enter your business email to continue!</div>";
    }

    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button> You are finally on the right path!</div>";
}
else {
$msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button> Something is really screwed up!</div>";
}
```